# animate svg fill in jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, background-color, fill

I want to change the fill of a svg with the help of waypoints.

For example, this is my code if I want to change the background-color. That works. BUT not for 'fill'.

```js
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('content-intro'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    $("#stickylogo svg").css({
      background: 'red'
    }, '5000');
  }
})
```

When I change "background:" to "fill:" it doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas how it's possible to change (or better animate) the fill of the svg?

Comment: What markup are you trying to apply this to?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].